# Modeling scientific theories with category theory (or, how to represent a biological system categorically)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, operads

Suppose I wanted to compare Linnaean classification, which arranges species by similarity in ranked taxa, to modern phylogenetic systematics, which appeals to descent with modification and branching trees. I want to represent the structure of each with category theory and then compare them so as to say how similar/dissimilar they are (fortunately for me, Baez has already formalized one phylogenetic model with operads: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03337).

**Roughly, the Linnaean system looks like this:**

There is class membership:

- individual organism (me) $\in$ lowest taxon (homosapien) $\in$ higher taxon (species)

and class inclusion where lower taxa are subsets of higher taxa:

- mammalia $\subset$ vertebrata

The classification is achieved through some similarity metric, where a certain amount of phenetic properties must be shared for two objects to belong to the same class.

How can this be represented categorically? Can we make the hierarchical relationships arrows, with the objects being the elements? Or would a higher structure be needed? I understand that the Baez operad paper uses topological operads, so would a metric space be more useful here if my aim is to compare the two? Or do I need higher structures? I'm a bit lost!

Comment: Have you looked at David Spivak's book "Category theory for the sciences"? It has lots of examples, and this might be in there. Anyway, it sounds like what you describe is a partial order on the set of taxa, and a ranking of taxa (kingdom, phylum, etc) is a morphism of partial orders.

Comment: What kind of applications are you looking for beyond "this looks like a tree"?

Comment: It is not an answer to your question. You could have a look at Mme Ehresmann's work about Memory Evolutive Systems: http://ehres.pagesperso-orange.fr/.

Comment: There's [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.03337). I haven't read it, but John Baez and Nina Otter use operads to study phylogenetic trees.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm hoping to do a structural comparison between the Linnaean system (which appears to be a partial order) and the Phylogenetic systematic system. We can make precise the structural continuity between classical mechanics and quantum mechanics with deformation theory, so I was hoping to do something similar here. How much structure is lost when we get rid of Linnaean classification and adopt phylogenetics?